# Aggregate only new rows from source table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I got one Source table with a timestamp column (YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS) and a target table with aggregated rows on daily basis (Date column: YYYY.MM.DD).

My Problem is: How do I bring new data from source to target and aggregate it?

I tried:

```
select
  a.Sales,
  trunc(a.timestamp,'DD') as TIMESTAMP,
  count(1) as COUNT,
 from 
 tbl_Source a 
 where trunc(a.timestamp,'DD') > nvl((select MAX(b.TIME_TO_DAY)from tbl_target b), to_date('01.01.1975 00:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))

group by a.sales,
  trunc(a.Timestamp,'DD')
```

The problem with that is: when I have a row with timestamp '2013.11.15 00:01:32' and the max day from target is the 14th of november, it will only aggregate the 15th. Would I use >= instead of > some rows would get loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your needs:

```
WHERE trunc(a.timestamp,'DD') > nvl((select MAX(b.TIME_TO_DAY) + 1 - 1/(24*60*60) from tbl_target b), to_date('01.01.1975 00:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

i.e. instead of 2013-11-15 00:00:00 compare to 2013-11-16 23:59:59

**Update**:

This one?

```
WHERE trunc(a.timestamp,'DD') BETWEEN nvl((select MAX(b.TIME_TO_DAY) from ...) AND nvl((select MAX(b.TIME_TO_DAY) + 1 - 1/(24*60*60) from ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont think so. Lets say in the Target my max date is 14th (because the day before the process aggregated a few rows with the timestamp close after 0 o clock) and in the source 15th 00:01:32. Now I need all rows that are between those two times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a merge statement: If the day is already present in tbl_target then update the count else insert the record.

```
merge into tbl_target dest
using 
(
  select sales, trunc(timestamp) as theday , count(*) as sales_count
  from tbl_Source
  where trunc(timestamp) >= ( select nvl(max(time_to_day),to_date('01.01.1975','dd.mm.yyyy')) from tbl_target )
  group by sales, trunc(timestamp)
) src
on (src.theday = dest.time_to_day)
when matched then update set 
  dest.sales_count = src.sales_count
when not matched then 
  insert (time_to_day, sales_count)
  values (src.theday, src.sales_count)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question: you need to get everything since the last reload to target table.

The problem here: you need this date, but it is truncated during the update.

If my guesses are correct you cannot do anything except to store the date of reload as an additional column because there is no way to get it back from the data presented here.

about your query:

1. count(*) and count(1) are the same in performance (proved many times, at least in 10-11 versions) - do not make this count(1), looks really ugly
2. do not use nvl, use coalesce instead of it - it is much faster
3. I would write your query like that:

   ```
   with t as (select max(b.time_to_day) mx from tbl_target b)
   select a.sales,trunc(a.timestamp,'dd') as timestamp,count(*) as count
   from tbl_source a,t
   where trunc(a.timestamp,'dd') > t.mx or t.mx is null
   group by a.sales,trunc(a.timestamp,'dd')
   ```